# Finding max row after groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a daframe as follows:

```
Month   Col1    Col2    Val
A       p       a1      31
A       q       a1      78
A       r       b2      13
B       x       a1      54
B       y       b2      56
B       z       b2      65
```

I want to get the following:

```
Month   a1  b2
A       q   r
B       x   z
```

Essentially for each pair of `Month` and `Col2`, I want to find the value in `Col1` which is has the maximum value.

I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

1. Find row with max `Val` within a group, which is `sort` and `drop_duplicates`, and
2. transform the data, which is `pivot`:

```
(df.sort_values('Val') 
   .drop_duplicates(['Month','Col2'], keep='last')
   .pivot(index='Month', columns='Col2', values='Col1')
)
```

Output:

```
Col2  a1 b2
Month      
A      q  r
B      x  z
```